# Removing the USB storage is removed notification

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, motorola-moto-g

My Moto G has USB OTG mass storage drivers - I can use a USB drive with a standard USB-OTG dongle for extra temporary storage.

This is *awesome* except for one thing -after I properly unmount and remove the USB drive I seem to be unable to dismiss the USB storage is removed notification until I reboot the phone.

[image]

Thats the notification I get. I can't slide to dismiss, and tapping on it throws me back into the home screen

I also have this little icon on top when I'm looking at other things

[image]

I'm running a Moto G XT1033 (8GB Asian edition) with the 4.4.2 update. I'm using a standard USB OTG adaptor with different USB drives, and as I said, have properly unmounted the drive (there's an error message if I'd been silly enough to do that). I've not rooted the phone in any way, and USB OTG mass storage support is natively supported.

Is there any way I can dismiss this notification *without* restarting my phone?

Comment: How are you unmounting the OTG USB?

Comment: The 'proper' way - telling it to unmount from storage -> "unmount shared storage"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah this happens on Moto X too. You can long press on the notification and click on App Info. Then force stop the application that posted the notification (System UI). Doing so doesn't seem to affect anything else. Annoying we have to do that but better than restarting phone.

Answer (score 3):

Thats probably a bug. Almost every moto g users are facing that issue. It is expected to be solved in the future update. Inform Motorola about your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that killing the process associated with the notification worked, with the annoyance of resetting my wallpaper. Plugging in something, then unplugging it *inappropriately* then swiping out the message for that seems to work perfectly. Of course, its still a bug, and its an utterly improper way to unmount a drive but it seems to work